# OroCRM - Installation Problems on Ubuntu 18.04 and CentOS 8

Tags: orocrm

**EDIT:** I just realized I was using version 2.4 or older and choosing a new version has been going on smoothly for now.

I'm trying to setup OroCRM on a VM using VirtualBox. I have tried using Ubuntu, MariaDB route using this [guide](https://websiteforstudents.com/install-orocrm-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04-with-apache2-mariadb-and-php-7-1/) but after getting to the logging in it sends me to a page where I have to update a lot of packages and it either times out or I get an error increasing the memory_limit and max_execution_time (which I did according to their suggestion).

After that, I tried following the [OroCRM documentation](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/dev-environment/manual-installation/crm-ce/#) but it gave me this [error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Qjcx.jpg)

So I'm just a bit lost on what to do next so any help or just pointing me to a general direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Mysql 8.0, but the only Mysql version compatible with OroCRM is 5.7.

Please make sure your VM meets all the [OroCRM system requirements](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/system-requirements/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just realized I've been downloading the older version of OroCRM, with the latest version everything has been going well so far